# SQL command isn't working

Tags: android, sqlite

```
    db.rawQuery("UPDATE listelement SET fkrid = (SELECT rid FROM room WHERE roomname = '" + roomFromEditText + "')", null);
```

This command is not working. The SQL Statement seem to be correct (I tried it in an SQL Browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()` for raw SQL queries that don't return data.

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but does not run it. `execSQL()` both compiles and runs it.